# How to convert dates to years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add another Column with only the Filing Year. Can anyone help me how to do it?

The current DataType of the Filing Data Column is Object. Is that okay or do I need to convert it?

```
        Issuer                      Filing Data
0       Lear Seating Corp           1994-03-08
1       Mississippi Chemical Corp   1994-07-14
2       Lucent Technologies Inc     1996-02-05
3       Ryerson Tull Inc            1996-05-07
4       Providence Journal Co       1996-04-22
```

BR and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the filing data column a string or a datetime variable?

Comment: ``df['Filing Data'].str.split("-").str[0]`` ?

Comment: The filing data column is a string. The suggestions from @sushanth worked. Thanks. Does anyone know how I can convert the Years from Int to Float?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Filing Data']).year
```

And here's the link:

https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/extract_month_year_pandas

Note : He uses this on a columns of type panda series

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Filing_Year'] = [val.split('-')[0] for val in df['Filing_Data']]
```

df:

```
                      Issuer Filing_Data Filing_Year
0          Lear Seating Corp  1994-03-08        1994
1  Mississippi Chemical Corp  1994-07-14        1994
```